# Could not find an overload for '=='

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I have the following code:

```
            var settingButton:UIButton
            settingButton = appDelegate.myFunctionReturningButton()

            if (settingButton == nil) {println("WE ARE IN BAD SHAPE!!!!")}
```

It partly works, but not always. To see what happens in case I do not get what I expect from myFunctionReturningButton(), I added the last line.
But here is the problem and my question:

I get this error message from the Swift compiler:

```
Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

Browsing the net, I kind of understand what that means, but what can I do about it?
How should I write the last line?

For precision:
I have the two following function in AppDelegate.swift and appSettingButton is declared with this line at the top of the AppDelegate class.

```
var appSettingButton: UIButton = UIButton.alloc()


func registerSettingButton (button:UIButton) {
    appSettingButton = button
}


func myFunctionReturningButton() -> UIButton {
    return appSettingButton
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code in `myFunctionReturningButton()` please?

Comment: OK. I have just edited the question to provide what you ask.
According to my present tests, it works at most one time and then crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a non-optional value to nil because it will never be nil.  And you shouldn't use `UIButton.alloc()` to initialize a button, just use `UIButton()`.  If your logic depends on waiting for this button to be re-defined after initialization of your app delegate subclass, you should make an optional, i.e. `UIButton?`.  Then you can compare it to nil.

Comment: This button is ready once registerSettingButton() has been called. I will try what recommend.

Comment: After making some changes, I got rid of the compile error. But I still have to make the program work as I want. By the way when changing UIButton to UIButton? where exactly do I need to make the change? Though I have now no more compile error does not mean I made the changes the way they should be made.

Comment: Instead of `var appSettingButton: UIButton = UIButton.alloc()`, change it to `var appSettingButton: UIButton?`.